# jQuery Mobile - dynamically add rel="external" to third level in a nested-list

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

How can I dynamically add rel="external" to the third level in a nested list?

I've tried:

```
$(document).live("mobileinit", function(){
 $("ul#globalMenu").listview();
});

$(document).live( 'pagebeforecreate',function(event){
 $('ul#globalMenu li ul li.menuList ul li a').attr('rel', 'external');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this selector `#globalMenu > li > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li > a`

Created a [**demo at jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/8negk/) for you.

`$('#globalMenu > li > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li > a').attr("rel", "external");`

It would also be possible to filter the selection by the number of parent `ul` elements but you should stick with the first suggestion.

```
$('#globalMenu li a').filter(function() {
    return $(this).parents('ul').length == 4;
}).attr("rel", "external");
```